# How to suppress "WARNING - Redeclared variable:" in Closure Compiler

Tags: javascript, compiler-warnings, google-closure-compiler, suppress-warnings

I have successfully suppressed some warnings in Closure Compiler with

```
/**                               
* @fileoverview                     
* @suppress {checkTypes|duplicate} 
*/
```

but I cannot find how to suppress "WARNING - Redeclared variable:"

What should I be using in the @suppress?

More generally, is there a list of the argument to use with @suppress given any error or warning?

Answer (score 2):

This should work ...

```
/** @suppress {duplicate} */ var dup;
```